# Open viewcontroller with textfield inside view xib file

Tags: swift, tableview, pushviewcontroller

I will explain the process before asking my question:

I have a tableviewcontroller, but i needed a textfield was always present at the hearing, to solve this problem i create a xib file with textfield inside and call the view with viewForHeaderInSection; at this point all is perfect.

i call the view whith this code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("createComment", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as? createComment
    }
```

My problem is next:

I want that when capturing text field starts a new window opens, something like what makes facebook to create a comment.

My code in createComment is:

```
class createComment: UIView, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var commentTextField: StyleComentTextField!
    weak var controller:tableComentVC!
    var currentController = tableComentVC()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.commentTextField.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        commentTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        if(textField == commentTextField){
             print("ok i tab in commentTextField")
            let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            self.controller?.navigationController!.pushViewController(storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("writeComment") as! writeComment, animated: true)
            resign()
            return false
        }else{
            return true
        }
    }

}
```

but this code dont work, the print in code works correctly, but i don't know why dont open the next viewcontroller.

Thanks!

Comment: What does happen then? Did you debug? Which variables are set and what to? Any errors or exceptions!

Comment: No, only print in log: ok i tab in commentTextField, but i dont have errors or exeptions, only don't open the next screen. . .